# Backbone.js model: attribute of type array maintains data between instances

Tags: arrays, backbone.js, coffeescript

Suppose I have following Backbone.js model:

```
    class App.Models.Article extends Backbone.Model
      defaluts:
        id: ''
        name: ''
        tags: []
```

and a view to display its contents. In a master view I create an instance of article view by passing a newly created Article as :

```
    v = new App.Views.ArticleView({ model: new App.Models.Article() })
```

and render it to the page.

In the article view and by user interaction some tags are added to the tags array by following code:

```
    addTag: ->        
      tags = @model.get('tags')
      tags.push({id: '', name: 'foo'})
      tags.push({id: '', name: 'bar'})
```

So far so good! Then I close the article view and render another view. Later I want to again render the article view so the code:

```
     v = new App.Views.ArticleView({ model: new App.Models.Article() })
```

runs again.

The problem is after rendering, I still can see previously entered tags in the tags array i.e. if inside articles view, I write:

```
     console.log(@model.get('tags'))
```

it will output two objects added before. I expect that each instance has its default values when created not something that there is no more reference to it. Any ideas? Any issues with Coffescript?

P.S. I hope the problem statement is clear enough :)

Comment: Even before I close the article view I call **@remove** to remove it and call **@model.clear().set(@model.defaults)**, still the same problem.

Comment: coffeescript produces **Article.prototype.defaults =** which attaches default values to the prototype of Article object. Maybe the problem is with that point?!

Comment: Nice question, why coffeescript compile things like that?! This also make problem with any attribute even non-array/object attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

The problem is that Coffeescript attaches default to the prototype, so defining the defaults as follows solves the problem:

```
    defaults: ->
      id: ''
      name: ''
      tags: []
```

Again it is attached to the prototype but as a function, it returns an empty object for each call.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use arrays and objects in defaults, they will get shared across model instances. If you want tags to be empty array, add that in initialize function.

```
var MyModel =  Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize:function(){
        this.set('tags', [])
    }
})
```